# Как исправить ошибку в VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Ошибка  CS1061  "Uslugi" не содержит определения "BtnEdit_Click", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "BtnEdit_Click", принимающий тип "Uslugi" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Этот код из окна с ошибкой:

```
  <DataTemplate>
   <Button Content="Редактировать" Name="BtnEdit" Click="BtnEdit_Click"></Button>
  </DataTemplate>
```

А этот уже из самого кода:

```
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для Uslugi.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Uslugi : Page
{
    public Uslugi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DGridPolicies.ItemsSource = Strahovanie_avtoEntities.GetContext().Policies.ToList();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Manager.MainFrame.Navigate(new AddEditPage());
    }
}
```

}

Проблема в том, что все делал по инструкции по созданию WPF приложения,
Сначала все было нормально, но в один момент скрины поменялись, и код, соответственно, тоже.
И, как раз-таки, в этот момент, появилась откуда-то кнопка "BtnEdit",
И нигде не написано, куда ее засунуть, как ее прописать, где.
В общем, сам не разберусь, помогите, пожалуйста...

На скринах прикрепил то, как код выглядел в инструкции.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что должно было получиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `private void Button_Click` и `Click="BtnEdit_Click"` - вы создали метод `Button_Click`, а ссылаетесь на метод `BtnEdit_Click`, не находите это подозрительным?

Comment: Так в этом и проблема, что я изменял все и везде, пытался название переписать,
Но ошибка не уходит никуда, я не понимаю, в чем загвоздка, что не так....

Comment: То что у вас показано в вопросе не соответствует тому, что вы пишете в комментарии.

Comment: Я поэтому и хочу понять, что я делаю не так,
И почему, не смотря на то, что я меняю названия метода,
Ошибка остается.
Я не хочу получить в ответ то, что и так понимаю,
Я хочу узнать, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Сделайте названия правильными и пересоберите проект, ну или запустите, ошибка должна уйти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя название Click-ивента кнопки в XAML файле и метода а XAML.cs отличаются.
Советую нажать на название Click-ивента в XAML, после этого нажать F12.
Автоматически создастся метод, внутри которого будет логика того, что происходит при нажатии кнопки